# TSQL MERGE Multiple Tables with Insert, Update, Delete

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, t-sql

I'm currently working on a stored procedure in T-SQL on SQL Server 2012. The task is really tricky: I need to merge (insert,update,delete) entries in multiple tables.

To facilitate, I try to explain my problem with 2 tables. I use Dapper in C# in an ASP.NET 4.5 MVC application and can control my Front-End. I'm passing into the stored procedure 2 Temporary Tables:

***Temporary Table Target:***

```
ID | TargetId | TargetGroupId | IsPublic | IsPrivate | 
---+----------+---------------+----------+-----------+
0  |    42    |   1           |   0      |  1        |
1  |    0     |   1           |   1      |  0        |
2  |    0     |   1           |   0      |  1        |
```

***Temporary Table Target Countries***

```
ID |CountryId | TargetId | 
---+----------+----------+
0  |    CA    |   42     |
1  |    FR    |   0      |
2  |    AU    |   0      |
```

The *TargetId 0* corresponds to a new entry, thus if the **TargetId = 0** I want to **Insert** or Delete an old record not from the list, if the **TargetId > 0** I want to **Update** the record.

The **final Result** could look like this:

**Table Target:**

```
| TargetId | TargetGroupId | IsPublic | IsPrivate | 
+----------+---------------+----------+-----------+
|    42    |   1           |   0      |  1        |
|    93    |   1           |   1      |  0        |
|    94    |   1           |   0      |  1        |
```

**Table Country:**

```
CId  |CountryId | TargetId | 
-----+----------+----------+
34   |    CA    |   42     |
35   |    FR    |   93     |
36   |    AU    |   94     |
```

So the new TargetId should be stored in Country as well. My current TSQL script looks like this:

```
DECLARE @TargetGroupId = 1;

MERGE [MySchema].[Target] AS [A]
USING @Targets AS [B]
ON ([A].TargetId = [B].TargetId)
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
    INSERT (TargetGroupId, IsPrivate, IsPublic)
    VALUES (@TargetGroupId, [B].IsPrivate, [B].IsPublic)

    -- Desired behaviour: doesn't work unfortunately...
    -- OUTPUT inserted.TargetId, [B].ID
    -- INTO #tmp;
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE
    SET [A].IsPrivate = [B].IsPrivate, [A].IsPublic = [B].IsPublic
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE AND [A].TargetGroupId = @TargetGroupId
    THEN DELETE;
```

This SQL script works fine for my table Target, but how can I update my second table Countries?

Do you know how solve this issue, thus to Insert, Update, Delete in a Merge Statement including several tables?

Thank you very much!!

Comment: Can you provide the error message?

Comment: What is the syntax error?

Comment: `MERGE` can only affect one table at a time. If you want to affect two tables you need to write two `MERGE`s

Answer (score -2):

```
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data source=.;initial catalog=db_futsal;integrated security=true");
    private void Peserta_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bind_data();
    }
    private void bind_data()
    {
        SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("Select no_peserta,nama As nama,asal As asal,tanggal_lahir from peserta", conn);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
        da.SelectCommand = cmd1;
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Clear();
        da.Fill(dt);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("Insert into peserta(no_peserta,nama,asal,tanggal_lahir)Values(@no_peserta,@nama,@asal,@tanggal_lahir)",conn);
        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("no_peserta", textBox1.Text);
        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("nama", textBox2.Text);
        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("asal", textBox3.Text);
        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("tanggal_lahir", dateTimePicker1.Value);
        conn.Open();
        cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();
        bind_data();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = "";
        textBox2.Text = "";
        textBox3.Text = "";
        dateTimePicker1.Text = "";
    }

    private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        int index;
        index = e.RowIndex;
        DataGridViewRow selectedrow = dataGridView1.Rows[index];
        textBox1.Text = selectedrow.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
        textBox2.Text = selectedrow.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
        textBox3.Text = selectedrow.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
        dateTimePicker1.Text = selectedrow.Cells[3].Value.ToString();

    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlCommand cmd3 = new SqlCommand("Update peserta Set nama=@nama,asal=@asal,tanggal_lahir=@tanggal_lahir where no_peserta=@no_peserta", conn);
        cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("no_peserta", textBox1.Text);
        cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("nama", textBox2.Text);
        cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("asal", textBox3.Text);
        cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("tanggal_lahir", dateTimePicker1.Value);
        conn.Open();
        cmd3.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();
        bind_data();
    }

    private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlCommand cmd4 = new SqlCommand("Delete from peserta where no_peserta=@no_peserta", conn);
        cmd4.Parameters.AddWithValue("no_peserta", textBox1.Text);
        conn.Open();
        cmd4.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();
        bind_data();
    }
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Comment: This code doesn't seem to have anything to do with the code in the question. Please read [answer].